# How to implement caching for Angular SPA

Tags: angular, caching, asp.net-core, single-page-application, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm developing Angular 7 application with backend in ASP.NET core. Application is hosted in Azure app service and SQL database is there as well. I noticed there are some tables that rarely change, like Countries table, but on the other hand, I need to use them often in my SPA. I wonder what caching solution would fit my case.

I haven't tried anything specific so far. Per my understanding, if I cache Countries on SPA side, I won't be able to access newly added ones (which happens from time to time) until the user reloads the page and application restarts. I know service like Redis cache would solve the problem but it's quite expensive. Since Azure App service can scale, I think I can't use solutions like SignarR as well. I was thinking of using push notifications, for example, https://www.telerik.com/blogs/push-notifications-in-asp-net-core-with-angular

I would like to hear if I'm right with my concerns and which is a recommended solution, with pros and cons, please :)

Comment: How about output caching? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: @UmutEsen Well, this is some possiblity, as it saves me from DB hit. It would require my SPA to call backend each time I need Countries though. Can you tell per your experience if concerns I listed are valid? I'm new to web app development.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have Dot net core api call to get the country list. In my opinion you should cache the api call which is actually getting the country list.

In spite of the fact that the apps are all data-driven and looked really dynamic, what really was changing in the same user session wasn’t that much, but we were making http requests for new content regardless.

**The easiest solution is caching**
Caching where? On the server? but this doesn’t stop all our apps hitting our services and thus — increasing the load on them.

Maybe we could use service worker since it allows caching API calls?
Yes, that was one of the options since it already has a pretty nice integration with Angular and allowed for a simple solution to selectively cache resources and APIs. However, what we wanted is to be able to not only choose what to cache, but also when to do it.

We Can actually cache all API call results, but only if we were certain that the data source did not change in some way.

If you are using Angular and Typescript, and all our data calls go through RxJs, we can create a Cache Observable decorator, which we’d use to only give the caching power to certain methods.

Before:

```
getCountry(take?: number, skip?: number) {
    return this.http.get(
      `${environment.api}/Country/latest?take=${take}&skip=${skip}`
    );
  }
```

it will become:

```
@Cacheable({
    cacheBusterObserver: CountryNotifier
  })
  getCountry(take?: number, skip?: number) {
    return this.http.get(
      `${environment.api}/Country/latest?take=${take}&skip=${skip}`
    );
  }
```

Notice that the @Cacheable() has been applied just to the method we wanted and was also passed cacheBusterObserver which is basically our Subject-based mechanism to tell this exact decorated method to relieve all its caches, when any value is emitted in that stream.

For example, the method below will “cache-bust” the caches of the method above, if the Observable it returns emits a value

```
@CacheBuster({
    cacheBusterNotifier: countryNotifier
  })
  saveCountry(id: string, name: string, review: string) {
    return this.http.put(`${environment.api}/Country`, {
      id,
      name,
      review
    });
  }
```

This might be the most complex example but we also have other configurations implemented like maxCacheCount, maxAge, slidingExpiration and custom cache deciders and resolvers which give us a fine-grain control on what, when and how to cache.

Comment: This could be good way to implement caching on SPA side, but won't help me if another instance of SPA will add a Country. For that case, orginal instance won't be able to notice that it still operates on old data.